# .htaccess redirect for subfolder images and stylesheets

Tags: image, .htaccess, stylesheet, subdirectory

Is it possible with a .htaccess redirect to have all style sheets and image paths, that are located in a subfolder, point to the appropriate folder(images/styles) in the the root folder? With out having to change the path in each file.

Let me try to explain my situation a little better.

Im using an include (header.inc.php) that contains my doctype, stylesheet links

```
    <link href="styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and a couple other html element/images.
That becomes an issue when header.inc.php in pulled into my subfolder files, because style/layout.css does not exist in that folder. Additionally there are 
a couple images that break because of the same reason,

```
    <img src="images/image.jpg">
```

the images folder does not exist…

In my current .htaccess file, I have the below script with my include path (for local testing). Is there something similar to the include_path script that can help with the issues listed above?

```
    php_value include_path ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/inc"
```

Here is an example of the file structure/hierarchy.

```
    [ROOT FOLDER]

    index.php

      /subfolder 
         subpage1.php
         subpage2.php
         subpage3.php

      /subfolder2
         subpage1.php
         subpage2.php
         subpage3.php 

     contact.php

     /images
     /styles
     /scripts
     /inc
```

Comment: Can you specify an example of what you want to go from and then to?

Comment: Hey baynezy, I updated my question. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: That is much clearer. I've now answered.

Comment: Thanks for your help, baynezy. I just applied your solution, and it is all linking as desired. I feel a bit silly for over complicating my problem!

Comment: Don't worry. As always it is easy when you know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use rewrites to solve this you just need to now how to define the source properly in your HTML elements.

Don't do this

```
<link href="styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Do this

```
<link href="/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

What this has changed is that your path is no longer relative to the file being browsed to but is now relative to the root of your web site.

Hope that helps.